# FFMPEG restream m3u8 to Youtube keeps returning "Failed to update header with correct duration & filesize" after 1st segment

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, rtmp, m3u8

I'm trying to retream a m3u8 live feed toYouTube but I keep running into errors.

When watching the feed in a webplayer it works fine.

The headers of the m3u8 file are as follow:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:127629
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2020-09-12T12:57:13.280Z
```

Here is the ffmpeg log:

```
frame=  226 fps= 25 q=29.0 size=    1303kB time=00:00:07.04 bitrate=1516.2kbits/frame=  238 fps= 

    25 q=23.0 size=    1414kB time=00:00:07.52 bitrate=1540.5kbits/[https @ 0x56067993d3c0] Opening 'fileurl.ts' for reading
    frame=  250 fps= 25 q=19.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:08.00 bitrate=1572.8kbits/frame=  251 fps= 24 q=17.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:08.04 bitrate=1565.3kbits/[flv @ 0x560679c4be40] 
Failed to update header with correct duration.
    [flv @ 0x560679c4be40] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
    frame=  251 fps= 22 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1851kB time=00:00:09.92 bitrate=1528.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=499 speed=0.859x
```

It seems like it loads 1 .ts file fine but fails after that.

I'm currently using:

```
ffmpeg -re -i (urlToM3U8) -codec copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/(streamkey)
```

Comment: did you find any solution, having exactly the same problem with an .avi